# Python FPDF How to display in 2 columns and to not split addresses when a new page is created

Tags: python, fpdf

'''
The module should read addresses from a text file,
lay them out in two columns ready for printing on
A4 self-adhesive paper.

The code I have is ok. But, I need it to display in 2 columns
and to not split addresses when a new page is created.

The addresses vary in size from 4 to 7 lines of text.

I've examined other's code but can't work out how to
achieve my goal.  Any help would be much appreciated.
'''

```
import os,sys
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('arial', '', 14)
w = 80

file = open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'addressbookMultiPrint.txt'))
for i, line in enumerate(file.readlines()):
    
    if i == 0:
        pdf.cell(w, 3, '', 'TLR', 1)
        
    pdf.cell(w, 7, line, 'LR', 1)
    
    if line == '\n':
        pdf.cell(w, 1, '', 'BLR', 1)
        pdf.cell(w, 3, ' ', 0, 1)
        pdf.cell(w, 3, '', 'TLR', 1)

pdf.output('single.pdf')
os.startfile('single.pdf')#,'print')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use **HTML**.

You need to make a table in HTML.

1. Import HTMLMixin. Don't forget to install FPDF2

   pip install fpdf2

   `from fpdf import FPDF, HTMLMixin`
2. Now we need variable with all HTML code

```
    html = '''
    <table width="100%">
    <tr><th width="50%">Header #1</th><th width="50%">Header #2</th></tr>
    '''
```

You may change 100% in the table if you don't want to make it so wide.

In **th** you may also change 50% if some of columns should be wider, but in total it must be 100%. (Even if your table is not 100%)

3. Your code with data

```
html += "<tr><td>" + name + "</td><td>" + surname + "</td></tr>"
```

4. Don't forget to close the table tag

```
html += "</table>"
```

5. Now, when all HTML is ready, pass it to the new class

```
class PDF(FPDF, HTMLMixin):
    pass

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()
pdf.set_font('arial', '', 14)
pdf.write_html(html)
pdf.output('single.pdf', 'F')
```

For more info check [this](https://pyfpdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/write_html/index.html#details)